# Making a 1m sized 16x24 screen so that the picture is recognizable

Tags: led, diy, led-matrix

I'm thinking about making a flexible LED screen with 16x24 LEDs.
I want the screen to be 1m wide so it will have big gaps between the LEDs.

Because of the big gaps I think the image may be unrecognizable.

How do I solve this problem? Use bigger LEDs? some kind of diffusers with small LEDs?

Comment: You might want to pull apart an old LED backlit LCD screen to see how it is done. They can be made quite thin.

Comment: thanks, will try to find info online, may be difficult to find an old one where I live, don't think people are disposing of them yet here.

Comment: @axk  On an unrelated note.  I like the cross-cultural picture on your avatar.  However, doesn't the tradition require 3 people?

Comment: I guess :) Thought it was really funny when first saw it back in 2008. Should look for one with Cheburashka :)

Comment: Could you describe the use case a bit more. Does it need to be LED:s? Could you consider cutting and driving some electro luminescent panels instead?

Comment: How good it looks is mostly related to the resolution of the image, not the gaps between them. Diffusers will help somewhat, you could go with a sheet in front or with individual diffusers. Some people have used Ping-Pong balls for this.

Comment: @axk  Is the viewer going to stand close to the panel?  Does the panel has to be thin?  Or, can it be, say, 0.5m deep?

Comment: I thinking of like a grid of wires with LEDs at the crossings all attached to a piece of transparent polyethelene film (probably similar to that they use for greenhouses) to hang in the window. The viewing distance 5m+